# fizzbuzz in assembly x86 outputs nothing

Tags: assembly, nasm, fizzbuzz

I am currently trying to make a program in assembly x86 that is compiled using nasm that outputs the numbers 1 through 20. if the number is a factor of three it outputs fizz otherwise it outputs the number.

my first question is how do I output a number as a decimal?

my second question is why does my code not output fizz and how do I go about making it do so?

```
section .data
fizz: db 'Fizz', 10
buzz: db 'Buzz', 10
fizzbuzz: db 'FizzBuzz', 10


section .text
global _start

_start:
mov rcx, 1

loop:
push rcx
xor dx,dx
mov ax,cx
mov bx, 3
div bx
cmp bx, 0
jz divisableby3

mov rax, rcx
jmp count

divisableby3:
mov rax, 1 ; 'write' syscall number
mov rdi, 1 ; stdout descriptor
mov rsi, fizz ; string address
mov rdx, 11 ; string length in bytes
jmp count

count:
pop rcx
cmp rcx, 21
jz exit
inc rcx
jmp loop


exit:
mov rax, 60 ; 'exit' syscall number
xor rdi, rdi
syscall
```

Comment: The only system call that you ever execute is number 60 (`sys_exit`).

Comment: Related: [FizzBuzz in assembly - segmentation fault](//stackoverflow.com/a/37494090) has my attempt at a tutorial on optimizing FizzBuzz.  It ended up kind of overcomplicated and maybe not a good tradeoff between code-size and branch-prediction but it does work.  Other answers on that question work, too.  BTW, 16-bit `div` isn't faster than 32-bit; just use 32-bit operand-size whenever it's convenient in 64-bit mode.